# How to correctly search for data between two dates

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve results that are in between two dates which are start and end date. (any two dates picked in the datetimepicker). The field is a datetime so maybe the time element has to be there as well? I want to be able to retrieve all the results , howeever something about my code is resulting in some of the results being ommitted.

```
var query = _repository.GetQueryable<Test>()
                .Include(s => s.Sector)
                .Include(s => s.Subject)
                .Include(s => s.TestType)
                .Where(x => x.CenterId == _user.CenterId);
                
            if (searcher?.GradeId is not null) query = query.Where(x => x.SectorId == searcher.GradeId);
            //if (searcher?.SubjectId is not null) query = query.Where(s => s.Subjects.Any(ss => ss.SubjectId == searcher.SubjectId));
            if (searcher?.SubjectId is not null) query = query.Where(s => s.SubjectId == searcher.SubjectId);

            if (searcher.FromDate.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.ExamDate >= searcher.FromDate && (!searcher.EndDate.HasValue || x.ExamDate <= searcher.EndDate));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the real problem is how to handle the optional start and end dates. Searching in a period is simple, assuming all fields and values are dates:

```
.Where(x => x.ExamDate >= startDate && x.ExamDate <= endDate)
```

If the fields contain a time component, it's easier to search from the start date, to before the day after the end date :

```
.Where(x => x.ExamDate >= startDate.Date 
         && x.ExamDate < endDate.AddDays(1).Date)
```

If you want different conditions, you can append them using different `Where` clauses. The question does that for the start date. It should do that for the end date as well :

```
if (searcher.FromDate.HasValue)
{
    if (searcher.EndDate.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.ExamDate >= searcher.FromDate 
                              && x.ExamDate <= searcher.EndDate);
    }
    else
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.ExamDate >= searcher.FromDate);
    }
}
```

Another option is to add each condition separately. This effectively creates combines them with `AND` by creating an outer query for every additional condition :

```
if (searcher.FromDate.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.ExamDate >= searcher.FromDate);
}
if (searcher.EndDate.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.ExamDate <= searcher.EndDate);
}
```